# My SVG is losing anchor points when I export it

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, export

I am having an issue when I go to export my svg. The green part of the svg loses anchor points and instead of being the shape of a leaf turns into an oval. I don't know what to do please help!

Here is what the svg is supposed to look like :[image: What the svg is supposed to look liek]

here is how it exports, the green shape loses the top and bottom point and becomes an oval... therefore sticking out from under the black...

[image: image that has been exported]

Here are the export settting I have used. I tried changing up a bunch of different things and nothing worked:
[image]

Comment: Can you press CMD+Y on MAC or CTRL+Y on PC and show us the outline of the green area?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest constructing this differently. It looks like you have separate shapes for the fills, rather than just simple filled and stroked shapes.  For SVGs, I've found it's always best to keep the construction of graphics as simple as possible, which will also help keep the file size to a minimum.

So, first I'd make a leaf shape from two intersecting circles, using the Shape Builder, then I'd duplicate the leaf shape and rescale to make a smaller one, and rotate around the bottom anchor, to get something like this.

[image]

Then I'd use the Shape Builder on the intersection, copy the resulting shape, and undo Ctrl+Z. Then paste in place.

The result is three independent shapes which can have fills applied. I've filled the middle intersection a darker green than the other two.

The mitre join of the corner of the middle intersecting shape will protrude  beyond the outline, but can easily be fixed using the Live Corner widget.

[image]

Here's the finished result:

[image]